# Uploading an image to Firebase Storage deletes the previous uploaded images automatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to code a ProfileActivity which will give you the option to upload an image with your name to it.

This is the upload function:

```
private void uploadFile(){


        final StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(getFileExtension(mImageUri));
        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri);

        fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                     @Override
               public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString().trim(), mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim());

                uploadID = mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim();
                mDatabaseRef.child(uploadID).setValue(upload);

            }
    })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. I see that all mImageUrl values on all parents changes to be that item I just uploaded.

My upload.class:

```
ublic class Upload {

private String mName;
private String mImageUrl;
private String key;

public Upload(){

    //constructor
}

public Upload(String name, String imageUrl, String id){

    if (name.trim().equals("")){
        name = "No Name";
    }

    this.mName = name;
    this.mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.key = id;
}
```

I am looking to upload an image everytime with a different name on mEditTextFileName, that will store the current uploaded image in Firebase Storage and won't change mImageUrl value on all parents.

Comment: Replacing old data is `expected` behavior when you are uploading/update image with same name

Comment: But if I want to store multiple users data? or multiple pictures/names...? its not really expected though.

Comment: name them differently `user1_picture1`, `user1_picture2` something like this

Comment: I tried naming them differently but then image won't show up at all.

Comment: you have to save all the name/urls of images in a arraylist in your user document. please tell me what is `uploadID`. **suggestion:** please give random String of 16 or more length to image name